# Going off balance and not making an attempt to hit during serve in squash. Is it a fault?

Tags: squash

In squash, after throwing the ball in the air, the serving player becomes off balance and makes no attempt to strike the ball. Is this a fault?

Answer (score 2):

As per section 4.3 under the [rules of service in squash as laid out by US Squash](https://www.ussquash.com/officiate/online-rules/#Service), the serve is not counted as a fault if the server makes no attempt to strike the ball.

> **4.3** To serve, a player shall release the ball from either a hand or the racket and then strike it. Should the player make no attempt to strike it after that release, the player shall release the ball again for that service.